# zsh auto-complete overflows emacs term-mode buffer

Tags: emacs, zsh, emacs24

I'm running zsh inside [`multi-term.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm) (which, as I understand it, is almost identical to term-mode with some additional commands) in character mode.

Edit: emacs 24.5.1 in a terminal (`-nw`), zsh 5.0.2, https://github.com/ayrtonmassey/config for my full config

When I hit `TAB` to invoke zsh's auto-complete, if the prompt is at the bottom of the screen the auto-complete options are hidden. This only happens on specific auto-completions: for example, pressing `TAB` after `cd` does *not* show the list of possible files/directories, but auto-completing names of executable files (e.g. typing `b` and hitting `TAB`) will show all the possible executables.

The currently selected auto-complete value is shown beside the prompt in all cases.

I assume this is something to do with it not scrolling down to show the output, but I can't find any more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, and after fiddling with the Customize group for `term`, it seems that setting the variable `term-scroll-show-maximum-output` to a non-nil value solves this problem (at least for `ansi-term`).

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem!